# Lining up colorplot data with axis ticks and click event coordinate data in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to embed a matplotlib colorplot in a tkinter window, and make it so that when the user clicks on a color block, the x and y data are printed to the console. Most of my problem arises from the fact that matplotlib likes the y-axis labels and y-coordinates to decrease as you rise vertically on the y-axis, which is the opposite of what I want. In attempting to reverse it, I'm messing something up that's causing the data I'm plotting to be shifted. I managed to get the x and y axis labels about where I want them, and when the user clicks on the graph, the x and y values that correspond to the ticks on the graph are printed (also how I want it to be). The issue is that the data being plotted is being shifted for some reason, so only the corner of it is visible. The ticks and labels of the axes should line up with the center of each block of color. Below is a simplified version of what I've attempted.

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


def onclick(event):
    print(event.inaxes)
    if event.inaxes!=None:
        print(event.xdata, event.ydata)

array=np.array([[12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
     [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
     [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])

rowLabels=[-2, -1, 0, 1] #these should increase from left to right on the plot
columnLabels=[-3, -2, -1, 0, 1] #these should increase from bottom to top on the plot

window=Tk()

fig=Figure(figsize=(10, 7))
graph=fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
im=graph.imshow(array, cmap='viridis')

xwidth=abs(columnLabels[0]-columnLabels[1])/2 
#half the distance between x values (padding for edges of plot)

ywidth=abs(rowLabels[0]-rowLabels[1])/2 
#half the distance between y values (padding for edges of plot)

graph.set_xlim(min(columnLabels)-xwidth, max(columnLabels)+xwidth) 
#adding and subtracting widths so that the ticks line up with the center of color blocks
graph.set_ylim(min(rowLabels)-ywidth, max(rowLabels)+ywidth) 
graph.set_xticks(columnLabels)
graph.set_xticklabels(columnLabels)

graph.set_yticks(rowLabels)
graph.set_yticklabels(sorted(rowLabels))

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=window)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
canvas.draw()


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to stumble upon a solution to my own question, so here it is.

The issue is that I wasn't telling matplotlib where on the graph I wanted it to start plotting, which needs to be done using the `extent` parameter in `imshow()`.

```
im=graph.imshow(array, cmap='viridis', extent=[min(columnLabels)-xwidth,
               max(columnLabels)+xwidth, min(rowLabels)-ywidth, max(rowLabels)+ywidth])
```